# gnetlist Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: spice

I am trying to use gschem/gnetlist/ngspice to do some circuit simulations. I have a subcircuit schematic and have created a symbol. I am able to add the symbol into the higher level schematic in gschem but when run gnetlist I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Found a placeholder/missing component, are you missing a symbol file? [<symbol file name>]
```

The device does not appear on the output netlist. The symbol file is in a subdirectory called "symbols" and in my ~/.gEDA/gafrc I have the line

```
(component-library "./symbols" "Local Symbols")
```

as per advice on the gnetlist mailing list but for some reason it still cannot find it, though gschem finds and uses the symbol without a problem. I've tried many things but I cannot get gnetlist to find the symbol. I've scoured the Internet for an answer to no avail and I posted here because there is apparently no simple way to post the question on the gEDA mailing lists. Anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this by looking at the gnetlist log files in ~/.gEDA/logs. The problem was that I had some things in my gafrc file that were valid for gschem but were not for gnetlist. As a result gnetlist was apparently not loading the rest of the file where the component-library command was. Once I removed the gschem-only commands, gnetlist was able to load the symbol and complete without any warnings. The subcircuit components were then in the output netlist as expected.